# Function that returns max element of an array of different types

Tags: c++, c++11, max

I have couple of compare function that go something like this:

```
int greater_than_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

and a max function that goes like this:

```
const void* max(const void *base, size_t members, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) {

char *base_ptr = (char *) base;
char max = *base_ptr;
for(int i = 1; i < nmemb; i++) {
    if (compar(&(*(base_ptr + i*size)), &max) != 0) {
        max = *(base_ptr + i*size);
    }
}
return &max;

}
```

When I try to run this function with `greater_than_int` I get nonsense results and since I'm still pretty new with C++ I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I've changed some things to my code but now it always returns max as 0. Still trying to figure out why, I appreciate all the people saying that this isn't the best way to do this but, unfortunately, this is the way that I have to do this.

Comment: [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: I have to write the max function myself, I can't use `std::max_element`

Comment: I didn't mean that you should use it - but look at the wiki. It's inspirational. The part "possible implementation" is great!

Comment: 99.99% of the time `void *` or `const void *` is used in C++ code, it is automatically wrong. Modern C++ never needs that. The only time such casts are used is to interface with C libraries. Using `void *` defeats C++'s built-in strong type system, and becomes a fertile ground for hard to diagnose bugs. Like this one. Going through the process of getting rid of all this, replacing it with proper, strongly typed, code or templates, will likely find the underlying source of the bugs. The compiler is almost guaranteed to find the underlying bug for you, now that it has actual types to play with.

Comment: I hear you, but in this case I have to use `const void *`

Comment: "_I have to use `const void *`_" - No, why? Not even your teacher can motivate that.

Comment: `int n = nmemb / size;` looks suspect to me.  So does `*max = *(base_ptr + i*size);`.

Comment: Yes, thank you I corrected it but it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: Noone should ever declare a function with the signature you struggle with. It's a pure waste of time.

Comment: ... and if all of that C-style calculations were replaced by appropriate C++-based iterators and container logic, the compiler would've automatically done those calculations, and done them correctly.

Comment: _Yes, thank you I corrected it but it still doesn't work properly_ Then please post your updated code.  Although I fear this is a hopeless case.

Comment: Why do you believe that you "corrected it" properly? Is it possible that whatever you "corrected it" to, is still wrong, but in a different way? Since you didn't realize the original version was wrong, is it possible that you don't realize that it's still wrong? Or it's maybe correct now, but other parts of the code that are not shown are still wrong, in the same way, so the results are still wrong. Until your shown code meets all requirements for a [mre], at most you can expect from others would be guesses at what all the problems are, here.

Comment: Oh, and irrespective of all the broken pointer logic, I see another obvious bug in the `max` function itself that has nothing to do with pointer calculations, but with incorrect use of pointers themselves. Something that in a proper, strongly-typed, `const`-correct code, would've been red-flagged by your C++ compiler in a heartbeat. `*max=*(base_ptr+i*size);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @samv manual vtable free type erasure (like writing a std any like type) should use void pointers, and is not C interop.

Comment: What you are trying to do just breaths template. `template <typename T> const T* max(const  T ...` or similar. `void*` is rarely something you should go for - anywhere

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont -- I'm fairly confident that none of the algorithms in the C++ library need to mess around with any class's vtable, in any form or fashion, including `std::any`.

Comment: @samv I said vtable free.  As in without using vtables.  I am saying doing type erasure without vtables requires using void pointers, or the equivalent.

Comment: What does it do @SamVarshavchik?

Comment: It does not, I repeat ***does not***, set `max` to point to the maximum value. The original version modified a single `char` value where `max` pointed to, by copying it from another pointer. Does that sound like what you want to do here? Of course not. Neither does the modified version. The shown code is hard to understand for the reasons that I already explained, and the correct approach to get reasonable, clear code is to rewrite everything from scratch using type-safe C++ code, and without any forced casts to void pointers.

Comment: This is the way that I have to write it, I'm very sorry if you are unable to understand that. Thank you for all the help, I'll figure it out.

Comment: Your instructor is teaching you C, even if they are telling you to put it through a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont is that an `any` without `bad_any_cast`? Just UB if you get it wrong? I'll stick to vtables, thanks

Comment: @caleth no?  Type checking does not need vtables.  C++'s vtable based polymorphism is just one implmentation of polymorphism you could write in C set up so C++ would auto write some of the code for you, while the standard intentionally left details vague to give compilers room to optimize.  If and when you benefit from alternative polymorphism implementation details, or want guarantees the standard leaves unspecified, you can implement alternative polymorphism in C++; usually with void pointers.  Post reflection (c++23 knock on wood) you'll even be able to automate much of it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not seeing how you can bypass the implementation's decisions about virtual functions in implementing an `any` type with the generality of `std::any`. What are you using if not `typeid`? "The `typeid` expression is an lvalue expression which refers to an object with static storage duration, of const-qualified version of the polymorphic type `std::type_info` or some type derived from it.".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont aside from that, writing your own dynamic polymorphism is a 0.01% kind of activity. `void *` is not needed by the majority of C++ programmers

Comment: @Caleth Yes, but I was responding to "The only time such casts are used is to interface with C libraries", which is simply *false*.  There is another reason to use such casts, so I described what that other reason is.  (A) `typeid` of a type doesn't use vtables (typeid on a vtable based polymorphic reference does!), (B) unique ids for types can be implemented without using `typeid` if you need different properties (you very rarely need this, typeid/typeindex is enough). Look, I'm not speaking academically. `function_view<Sigs...>` is useful and missing in the C++ standard library, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're forced to work with those function signatures, here's one way of dealing with them.

```
// I suggest changing this to `bool`, but you can leave it as `int` if you must
bool greater_than_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
    // no need for `if(...)` - just return the result of the comparison
    return *static_cast<const int*>(a) > *static_cast<const int*>(b);
}
```

Then, the actual `max` function has some problems where you define `max` as a `char` and not a pointer etc. `max` can be left as a `const void*` since you don't need to perform any pointer arithmetics with it. I'm using `base` as the pointer to the maximum element below instead.

```
#include <iterator> // std::next, std::advance

const void* max(const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                bool (*compar)(const void*, const void*))   // note: bool here too
{
    if(nmemb) {
        // no need to cast away const:
        auto current = static_cast<const char*>(base);
        auto end = std::next(current, nmemb * size);

        for(std::advance(current, size); current != end; 
            std::advance(current, size))
        {
            if(compar(current, base)) base = current;
        }
    }
    return base;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oxe3Gb18f)

Comment: Thank you for the response, how do I call this properly? I tried like this: `mymax(arr_int, 9, sizeof(int), greater_than_int)`  where arr_int is an array where I'm trying to find the max value and 9 is number of elements inside of it but when I run that I get something likes this: `0xffffcc18`

Comment: @WholesomeGhost You're welcome. Do you mean [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/5ETx5rajo)?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.